# Appengine glcoud command not found after install

Tags: php, google-app-engine

After running the php GoogleAppEngineLauncher launching it and then restarting the command line gives as follows

gcloud auth login
-bash: gcloud: command not found.

Two weeks ago there was another step that is now missing in the docs along with components update. Please advise if this is still necessary.
Note I have the following in the /usr/local folder.

google_appengine

google_appengine.old

Currently installing 1.9.23 on a Mac OS 10.10

Comment: deleted the local appengine, .old and the application GAE launcher and Installed version 1.9.24 and still getting the same bash error on gcloud auth login. Isn't the simlinks supposed to take care of the bash settings?

Comment: The `gcloud_sdk` should have created `~/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc` - do you have this file? (Mine is installed in my home directory by default). This should be added to your `.bash_profile` somehow. Do you see it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, No, the installer places a GAE launcher in the applications folder and I can launch it but no google-cloud-sdk folder in sight

Comment: Ah - thanks. The Mac OSX SDK instructions have changed recently. I've always used `gcloud` for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue caused by relying on `GoogleAppLauncher` instead of installing and using `gcloud`. (You should be able to do both).

### Installing `gcloud`

[Start here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) to make sure you have `gcloud` installed.

I doubt `gcloud` is packaged with `GoogleAppLauncher`, but I have not confirmed.

### Why isn't it already like this?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads explains that symlinks may be created when installing the MAC version. If you skip this, you won't have access to `appcfg.py` or the appengine specific includes.

`gcloud` is a larger SDK package which manages all google cloud components. It has always been best practice for us at Loudr to use `gcloud` across the board.

Comment: Ok thanks. FYI - Its currently missing from the php quickstart docs tho, that step was there two weeks ago

Comment: Looking at `google-app-engine` on stackoverflow as a whole, it looks like some changes to the PHP launcher docs are creating a breaking experience for new developers.

Comment: No I knew that and always approve sim link changes every time I installed. So your saying the upgrade should do the sdk install ? Wow that will be fantastic but might still need a second look

Comment: All I can discern right now is that `gcloud` is not made instantly available to your terminal. This is either through missing symlinks, broken path, or otherwise. Without diving into your internals, I know you can get `gcloud` up and going quickly by following the first link and following the instructions - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/   - i think a larger but separate issue is `gcloud` missing but implied in the docs